# How to do 3D audio?

Tags: audio

There is the concept of audio played at specific locations relative to the listener, such as in games.

- What are the details of how this is accomplished in stereo or higher number of channels?
- I know that there is volume adjustment and delaying of playback for the farther ear (in the case of stereo), but does anyone know the details of that?
- Are there other considerations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first, there is a difference between doing this with headphones or doing this with a pair or larger collection of loud speakers.

there are a few basic physical and physiological mechanisms:

1. [**interaural time difference**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaural_time_difference) (ITD) from which [Blumlein stereo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blumlein_Pair) is based on.  this is the most salient or precise [cue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensory_cue) to locate the azimuth angle (where in front or behind of the listener, from left to right) of a sound source, but it does not differentiate between whether the source is in front or rear or above or below. if you can imagine an axis that goes through your head, from left to right, where your ears (or ear openings) are, if a sound at, say 40° left from directly in front, causes the sound to arrive at your left ear 450 microseconds before arriving at your right ear (that's the ITD), there is an imaginary cone centered on that axis with the same 40° going around and **all** sources of sound lying on that cone will have the same ITD.  you cannot tell if it's 40° left of front or 40° down from straight up (on the left) or 40° left of directly behind or 40° up from straight down (on the left).  ITD is only about the time difference, it is not the model of front vs. up vs. behind vs. down.

http://interface.cipic.ucdavis.edu/images/research/pathgeo.gif

2. [**head-related transfer functions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-related_transfer_function) (HRTF) which models the [pinna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auricle_(anatomy)) of the ear (and perhaps head shading, but i think that is less salient).  because the pinna shape is not the same viewed from in front or behind or above, the *"pinna cues"* are what will tell your brain where the sound source might be in addition to the information coming from ITD.  [this looks like a good tutorial for HRTF.](http://interface.cipic.ucdavis.edu/sound/tutorial/hrtf.html)

[image]

[image]

oh, there are a few more physical mechanisms. (the above two mechanisms will give the listener an azimuth and elevation angle, but not distance or depth.)

3. **inverse-square law with distance.**  every time you double the distance of the sound source from the listener, the power intensity (watts per square meter) is reduced by a factor of 4 (the "voltage" level is cut in half) which is a 6 dB drop in the signal level.
4. **filtering from distance.**  in addition, high frequencies are sometimes attenuated by distance and by reflections off of soft surfaces more than low frequencies.  the transfer function is not only a delay ($e^{-s\tau}$)  so distant sounds might be a little bit low-pass filtered, less "crisp", than sounds that are much closer.  consider the classic movie effect sound of the [pump-action shotgun being actuated](https://www.audioblocks.com/stock-audio/shotgun-pump-action-sound-effect.html).  consider what that will sound like if it is up close or further away.  it won't only be quieter when further away, but a little less crisp.
5. **direct/reflection energy ratio.**  if the brain decodes multiple arrivals of a sound that are correlated, the first arrival might be considered the direct path and the latter arrivals are reflections.  if the energy of the direct is much more than the energy of the reflections, the sound might be perceived to be closer.  if the energy of the direct is at about the same energy as that of the reflections, the sound might be perceived to be farther away.

[image]

i s'pose i could blap some transfer function - matrix math to outline the HRTFs from source to each ear.  that will take more time to look up.  don't wanna do this from out of my memory.  [here's a good Wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_localization)

Comment: Thanks rbj. Do you happen to know how much of that is actually used in practice? Preferably for real time processing, but non real time is useful information as well.

Comment: well, i don't know about the games.  for stereo music, perhaps only the Blumlein pair of mic-ing is done.  i think for expensive, high-quality sound effects for movies, maybe all of these perceptual mechanisms are addressed.  it's **all** linear, time-invariant processing unless the sound source is moving, and then it's linear but not time-invariant.  the reverb might be a little expensive (but not prohibitive) for real time, the filtering in 4 and 2 are cheap enough.  the ITD requires a fractional delay filter.  it can all be done in real time.

Comment: I've read that some implementations also simulate reflection of sound from the listener's shoulders. This makes sense if it is reasonable to assume that the listener always looks forward (e.g. at a screen) or you have information on the relation between their head and body.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a definitive answer, can only report on what I came up with and tried so far, in a very recent experiment. It seems to be fairly effective, at least for an aural world primarily consisting of an X-axis, Z-axis plane. There is probably considerable room for optimization of the algorithm.

Let's say we have a camera-eye location that is moving about the 3D world. I maintain the location of two virtual "ears", a fixed distance 90 degrees left and right from the direction the camera is pointing, corresponding to what we might call a virtual head. I determine the distance of the sound to each ear and calculate the difference. The sound is placed in a stereo delay line consisting of an array of 32 frames (to approximate the amount of time, at 44100 fps, that matches the speed of sound in air and the size of a real-world head). The number of frames may not be optimal. A dedicated "read head" (for that sound) is positioned on the lagging stereo channel based on the time difference. Linear interpolation is used in the reading of the signal when the calculated "read" position does not lie squarely on a given sound frame.

This seems to me to be more convincing than using volume differences, especially since the lagging ear, with volume diffs, can receive a significantly quieter signal, and thus not mask other sounds properly. IMHO, an ear turned away from a nearby, loud jackhammer should not be able to hear other quieter, more distant sounds because the jackhammer has been attenuated to that ear to achieve a stereo placement.

The texts that I have found so far seem to rely on filtering and attenuation rather than on delay, and rely on math that is harder for me to follow than the simple trig needed to calculate distance differences. I'm still looking for a more definitive answer, and will be monitoring this question to see what else comes up.

I posted a demo/example file (java jar can be downloaded and run) on java-gaming.org [3D audio test](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/3d-audio-test-using-javafx-and-procedural-java-sound/37238/msg/355133/view.html#msg355133) to solicit comments. I got some interesting feedback similar to that which you received from robert bristow-johnson. I haven't tried filtering in real time yet, for HRTF. Presumably, a bit of low-pass filtering can be done relatively inexpensively, and be "good enough" for some game applications where an amount of distance or an acoustic obstruction (and muffling) needs to be indicated by the sound.

Comment: oh, the Blumlien model **definitely** is based on delay.  more so than amplitude difference.

Comment: Thank you Phil! Rbj gave a lot of completely accurate info for me to investigate, while you gave me some very practical advice. I'll have to start with your excellent info and see what of rbj's I can add.  Thanks man!

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson Yes, many interesting links! Much here for me to pursue further, thank you! One thing: I'm not clear how delay comes into picture in Blumlien. The mics are so close to each other, sound would be arrive at each at close to the same time, yes? (human ears are further apart) In a game, are we assuming stereo assets recorded via Blumlien are more conducive to playback with delay applied to one ear or the other than other forms of stereo recording? I have only tried applying the delay effect described above to mono assets.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner, the Blumlien pair are cardiod mics, which means that they are directional.  if exactly what Blumlien was designing for their gain or sensitivity would be proportional to $\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle as measured from straight ahead off of the front of the microphone.  the next thing you have to look at is how, in the Blumlien model, the two loudspeakers combine at the ear.  so while **delay** difference is the perceptual model, it gets accomplished with stereo speakers using a $\sin \ \cos$ amplitude mixing.  funny, eh, but that's how the math works out.